# Переполнение строки

Tags: c++, строки

Проблема в том что компилятор на 48 и 51 строчке жалуется на переполнение строки , можете обьяснить в чем причина , я не совсем понимаю

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
void Numbers(char A[],char B[], char C[])// перевод из символов в числа
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        A[i] -= '0';
        B[i] -= '0';
        C[i] = 0;
    }
}
void Symbols(char A[], char B[], char C[]) // перевод из чисел в символы
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        A[i] += '0';
        B[i] += '0';
        C[i] += '0';
    }
}
void Summ(char A[], char B[], char C[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        C[i] += (A[i] + B[i]) % 10;
        C[i + 1] += (A[i] + B[i]) / 10;
    }
}
int main()
{
    //Начальные числа 
    string digit_A, digit_B;

    //Массивы для длинной арифметики
    char A[300], B[300], C[300];
    
    //Ввод чисел
    cout << "Enter the first number.." << endl;
    cin >> digit_A;
    cout << "Enter the second number" << endl;
    cin >> digit_B;
    
    //Зеркальное копирование в массивы A,B (для удобства)
    for (int i = 300; i >= 0; i--)
        A[i] = digit_A[i];

    for (int i = 300; i >= 0; i--)
        B[i] = digit_B[i];

    Numbers(A, B, C);
    Summ(A, B, C);
    Symbols(A, B, C);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы бы строки выделяли в тексте комментарием, например,, а то считать до 48 я лично, хоть и умею, но ленюсь :)

У вас массив какой? Например, `A`?

```
char A[300]
```

то есть это элементы в С/С++ и множестве других языков, где отсчет начинается с 0 - с номерами от `A[0]` до `A[299]`.

К каким элементам вы обращаетесь здесь?

```
for (int i = 300; i >= 0; i--)
    A[i] = digit_A[i];
```

К 300, 299, 298, ..., 1, 0.

Нестыковку не замечаете? Выделили 300 элементов, обращаетесь к 301.

Я уж молчу, что в `digit_A` может быть, скажем всего 3 символа. Что вы копируете (кстати, никак не "*зеркально*") в 300-й символ? Если в `digit_A` их, скажем, только 10? выход за пределы выделенной памяти, UB.

Вот пример (ну, не самый эффективный...) суммирования строк. Защита от дурака отсутствует.

```
string Summ(const string& a, const string& b)
{
    string s;
    int c = 0;
    for(auto ia = a.rbegin(), ib = b.rbegin();
        ia != a.rend() || ib != b.rend();)
    {
        char r =
            ((ia == a.rend()) ? 0 : *ia++ - '0') +
            ((ib == b.rend()) ? 0 : *ib++ - '0') + c + '0';
        if (r > '9')
        {
            c = 1; r = r - 10;
        }
        else c = 0;
        s = r + s;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: не совсем понятно , почему будет переполнение , если в digit_A будет 10 символов , с i=300 понял , у меня ошибка , должно быть 299

Comment: можете пожалуйста поподробнее обьяснить?

Comment: Такой вопрос : вот если я ввожу строку например : 1234 ,то какой у меня лимит по символам (памяти ) будет ? если не ошибаюсь , в строке остальные символы сразу инициализируются нулем

Comment: имею ввиду лимит в string

Comment: Ну берем `i == 300`. `digit_A == "23132131"` Скажите, что будет при присвоении `A[300] = digit_A[300]`. Чему равно `digit_A[300]`? Их НЕТ. Вы можете добавлять в строку что хотите - она будет расти. Но как вы себе представляете "в строке остальные символы сразу инициализируются нулем" - какие символы? **Сколько**? Сто, тысяча, миллиард? Сколько? Строка внутри - динамически выделенный массив. Такой же, как ваш `A` - ну, со своими тонкостями. Но для понимания сойдет. Считали 10 символов? Массив из 10 символов. Добавили еще 10? Выделили новый массив на 20 символов, перекопировали, старый убили...

Comment: Заранее извиняюсь , опыта работы со строками мало , начинающий

Comment: ну по сути оно не проинициализировано , или равно нулю

Comment: я рассчитывал на то , что оно будет равнятся нулю

Comment: кажется ,я понял , получается нужно сначала проинициализировать нулями до нужного элемента , а потом выполнять действия ? (с помощью функции numbers , которая у меня в коде)

Comment: И совершенно напрасно. Можно и так, но проще саму задачу делать по-другому...

Comment: А каким именно способом ? опишите вкратце, мне хочется узнать

Comment: Что именно? Получить обратную строку? `reverse(digit_A.begin(),digit_A.end())`. Если же просто длинное суммирование - то в комментарии не ответишь, места мало :)

Comment: Набросал в ответ пример решения задачи - суммирование двух чисел, представленных строками, в строку же...